# Why am I getting "Data conversion or data mapping error. SQLCODE=-802" on a simple DB2 select statement?

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I am accessing DB2 information on an IBM i (AS400) with PHP.

With this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM QS36F.MYTABLE WHERE MYFIELD=120006";
$result = db2_prepare($conn, $query);
db2_execute($result);

$i=0;
while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($result) or die(db2_stmt_errormsg())){
    $i++;
    print "Row " . $i . " successful<br />";
}
```

I get:

> SELECT * FROM QS36F.MYTABLE WHERE MYFIELD=120006
>
> Row 1 successful
>   Row 2 successful
>   Row 3 successful
>   Row 4 successful
>   Data conversion or data mapping error. SQLCODE=-802

There should be more than 4 results.
Why might this error be occurring?

More details:

- This same error seems to happen on any value I search for in MYFIELD although it may be after a different number of successful results
- MYFIELD is NUMERIC(7,0)
- I can search other fields in the table(including numeric ones) and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was invalid decimal data in the table. There were blanks instead of zeros. I moved zeros into those blanks and that fixed the problem

Comment: How did you find this? I have the same issue, but I can't find the bad data.

Answer (score 2):

If it can help someone else, I had the same error and found out I was making a **join between mismatching data types**: a `DECIMAL(2,0)` field and a `VARCHAR(5)` field. Till we have `VARCHAR`s that can be converted into `DECIMAL(2,0)` it can work, otherwise it throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [SQL0802](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0802.htm) is arithmetic overflow.  More than likely one of the rows has a data value that is too big for the php variable that you have declared for it, although I can't see that in the code you've posted.  Or else there is some other funny data conversion not happening properly, for example if the QS36F.MYTABLE object is actually a view that is selecting from another table, and is converting one of the columns.

Comment: MYTABLE is not a view. How could a data value be to big for the php variable? I have tried doing a select that just return one column. So I think that would eliminate the possibility that $row is being overloaded.

Comment: It might be easy to overflow a PHP variable. But because you're using `SELECT * FROM...` and there are no column definitions shown to us, we can't tell why it's happening here. In production code, `SELECT * FROM...` should essentially never be used; specify an explicit _column-list_ or simply accept that various answers will never be found.