# AS400 Query/Excel ODBC Union Error

Tags: sql, db2, odbc, union, ibm-midrange

I'm having issues getting a query working in Excel for our AS400/DB2 system.

I'm trying to use two different tables with different info, but return an aisle/slot in the same column based upon a specific SKU/Customer ID(Storer). I thought a UNION would work but I get an "SQL0802 - Data conversion or data mapping error" when trying to run the query.

Here's what I have right now:

```
SELECT ADJTRAN.AJAISL AS AISLE, ADJTRAN.AJSLOT AS SLOT
FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ADJTRAN ADJTRAN
WHERE (AJITEM=8011989 AND AJSTOR=581)
UNION
SELECT ILCATER.ILAISL AS AISLE, ILCATER.ILSLOT AS SLOT
FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ILCATER ILCATER
WHERE (ILITEM=8011989 AND ILSTOR=581)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: AJAISL, AJSLOT, ILAISL and ILSLOT are character fields with a length of 4.

Comment: In UNION operation you must have same number of columns and their data types as well. Please verify it with both tables columns data types what you are selecting.

Comment: The columns being selected all have the same data type. Edited the question to state this.

Comment: You say they are all CHAR(4). Can you show us (copy/paste) where you see those data definitions?

Comment: Are ADJITEM, ADJSTOR, ILITEM, ILSTOR integer fields?

Comment: Given [the root cause discovered in this question about 802](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009180/why-am-i-getting-data-conversion-or-data-mapping-error-sqlcode-802-on-a-simp), it sounds like your table probably has bad data.

Comment: Please do a DSPFFD and paste in the definitions of all of the columns in the query, including the columns being used in the WHERE clause.  If it turns out that the columns all correspond in type, then there may be decimal data errors in one of the tables.  Break the UNION apart and see if each one runs separately.  One note: searching with 'AS/400' will return an ugly mix of ancient (worthless) results and current.  Try 'IBM i' or 'DB2 for i' for only current results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJITEM and ILITEM are VARCHAR(20). I was comparing it to an INT. Fixed and the code below works with zero issues. My fault for not stating this in the original question and overlooking such a simple mistake.

```
SELECT ADJTRAN.AJAISL AS AISLE, ADJTRAN.AJSLOT AS SLOT
FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ADJTRAN ADJTRAN
WHERE (AJITEM='8011989' AND AJSTOR=581)
UNION
SELECT ILCATER.ILAISL AS AISLE, ILCATER.ILSLOT AS SLOT
FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ILCATER ILCATER
WHERE (ILITEM='8011989' AND ILSTOR=581)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at the data found in the columns being selected, `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` is likely to help you.

Try something like —

```
SELECT CAST( ADJTRAN.AJAISL AS VARCHAR(128) ) AS AISLE, 
       CAST( ADJTRAN.AJSLOT AS VARCHAR(128) ) AS SLOT
...
UNION
SELECT CAST( ILCATER.ILAISL AS VARCHAR(128) ) AS AISLE, 
       CAST( ILCATER.ILSLOT AS VARCHAR(128) ) AS SLOT` 
...
```

**EDITED TO ADD**

Given that all *selected* columns are the same data type, it's probably one of the *tested* columns that's at issue.

You're comparing what look like `INTEGER`s to values in `AJITEM`, `AJSTOR`, `ILITEM`, and `ILSTOR` -- but what types are these columns, and is all data strictly conformant to that type?

One troubleshooting strategy is to try smaller versions of your query, and gradually add elements, until you find the error trigger.  Here, I'd try each part of the `UNION` separately, at least, if not one element of the `WHERE ... AND` therein.

Comment: Tried cast as varchar(4) and cast as char, same error being generated. 

Even tried concatenating both IE: 
`CAST(AJAISL||'/'||AJSLOT AS VARCHAR(9))`

Comment: In this CASE it's not good to use conversion or casting, first preference is to have the same data, it might be the problem of data, can you please provide the data structure and set so that we can find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime Excel have bugs... Can you try it:

```
    select * from (
    SELECT ADJTRAN.AJAISL AS AISLE, ADJTRAN.AJSLOT AS SLOT
    FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ADJTRAN ADJTRAN
    WHERE (AJITEM=8011989 AND AJSTOR=581)
    UNION
    SELECT ILCATER.ILAISL AS AISLE, ILCATER.ILSLOT AS SLOT
    FROM S216F06V.WDLSDATA.ILCATER ILCATER
    WHERE (ILITEM=8011989 AND ILSTOR=581)
    ) tmp
```